# Sorting an array of string data using the insertion sort method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm having trouble using insertion to sort an array of strings.

When I compile the following code:

```
public class Project1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String names[]=new String[5];
        int size=names.length;
        System.out.println("Enter the 5 car manufacturers: ");
        //Load Array
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            names[i] = input.nextLine();            
        }

        //Print descending order list
        String[] descSort;
        descSort=bubbleSortDesc(names);
        System.out.println("Car manufacturers listed sorted in descending order (via BubbleSort): ");
        for (int x=0; x < names.length; x++) {
            System.out.println(names[x]);
        }

        //Print ascending order list
        insertionSortAsc(names, size);
        System.out.println("Car manufacturers listed sorted in ascending order (via InsertionSort): ");
        for (int z=0; z < names.length; z++) {
            System.out.println(names[z]);
        }
    }¨

    public static String[] bubbleSortDesc(String[] names) {
        String temp;
        int passNum, i, result;
        for (passNum=1; passNum <= 4; passNum++) {
            for (i = 0; i<=(4-passNum); i++) {
                result=names[i].compareToIgnoreCase(names[i+1]);
                if(result<0) {
                    temp=names[i];
                    names[i]=names[i+1];
                    names[i+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return names;
    }

    public static void insertionSortAsc(String[] names, int i) {
        String temp = names[i];
        int j = i-1;
        while (j >= 0 && names[j].compareToIgnoreCase(temp) > 0) {
            names[j+1]=names[j];
            j--;
        }
        names[j+1]=temp; 
    }

    public static void insertionSort(String[] names, int n) {
        for(int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
            insertionSortAsc(names, i);
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me the error:

```
cannot find symbol- method insert(java.lang.String[], int)
```

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that we were told to use our book as reference for the code, yet the book only deals with sorting data of type int and there are no examples for sorting string data.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: After fixing the error, the program compiles and executes but after inputting the data it crashes and gives me the following error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException:
5
```

This error highlights the line `String temp = names[i]`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a method named insert.

Comment: I was under the impression that it was a pre-loaded method from the way the book put it, thanks for the input.

Comment: It might be, but you still need to add it to your class path or reimplement it, probably the latter.

Comment: Do you have any input into the new problem after inputting the data?

Comment: @user3385542 What? I don't understand what you just said.

Comment: I made an edit that explains the new problem, but basically after executing the program and inputting the 5 strings it crashes out with the error message "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException:
5", I was wondering if you knew what was causing that error message.

Comment: Can you add stack trace and the new method?

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException means that at that line the program is accessing an array past its bounds; with the actual code and line numbers it's pretty easy to locate the bug.

Answer (score 0):

This will work the way you intend:

```
public static void insertionSortAsc(String[] names, int n)
{
    for(int i = 1; i<n; i++)
    {
        insert(names, i);
    }
}

public static void insert(String[] names, int i)
{
    String temp = names[i];
    int j = i - 1;

    while (j >= 0 && names[j].compareToIgnoreCase(temp)  > 0)
    {
        names[j + 1]= names[j];
        j--;
    }
    names[j + 1] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void insertionSort(int... arr) {
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= arr[i - 1])
            continue;

        int j = i - 1;

        for (; j >= 0; j--)
            if (arr[j] < arr[i])
                break;

        int tmp = arr[i];
        System.arraycopy(arr, j + 1, arr, j + 2, i - j - 1);
        arr[j + 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```